Can the speed of light inhibit the synchronisation of a power grid?
As far as i know the following are true:

for a power grid to work properly, the voltage supplied by all the generators has to be relatively synchronised at every point in the grid, especially at the generators themselves.

changes in electric fields travel at a finite speed $c$ in any reference frame.


This seems to me to give a contradiction for the proper working of grid power for a sufficiently large power grid. Since 2 generators A and B at a distance $d$ would experience a lag of $d/c$ between them, so say A is synced to the voltage it receives from B, then B receives the voltage from A with a phase delay of $2d/c$. If then $d=c/4f=1500km$ at 50Hz, The voltage from A would be opposite that of B causing a short circuit at B. Since $O(1500km)$ is a scale on which some power grids operate, how come light delay and the resulting interference are not an issue?

Can you clarify "synced to the voltage", sync in terms of voltage magnitude, angle, and/or the frequency?

@goldboy it has to be the same frequency, phase and magnitude in order for the current and as such the power to add up afaik.

Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

I wonder why the (admittedly simplified) explanation of "the generator synchronizes to the local state" isn't good enough for you? Generators aren't globally synchronized - they don't synchronize with an atomic clock or something. The same thing that makes the e.g. phase delayed also does the same to the "signalling" the generator uses to synchronize. And indeed, they are never perfectly synchronized even then - every time the load (or supply) changes, the phase shifts until the generators can accommodate the change. Improper synchronization gets you kicked out (or faults the grid).

@Luaan without the Phase shift transformers mentioned below  it is physically impossible for generators at a sufficient distance from eachother to both locally synchronise, the best synchronisation compromise in that case is either lowering/increasing the frequency quite drastically, or both being 90° out of phase with the other's signal. Remember that a signal locally synchrosied also travels back down to the other generator. I am asking this question as a curious physics student, not as some kind of disbeliever in electricity...

You are correct, so what does the industry do?
Grid Design and Control:
Power grids are engineered to account for phase differences and signal propagation times. They use various devices, such as phase-shifting transformers and reactive power compensators to manage and adjust phase relationships.
Generators locally and across the entire grid use sophisticated control systems accounting for delays in signal propagation such as phasor measurement units (PMUs) to monitor/adjust voltage Phase at different points in the grid in real-time.
Strategic segmentation of the grid also adds to the prevention of the kind of destructive interference that you described.

Even worse than that - any piece of wire has its own inductance and capacitance, which are non-negligible when the line is long. Essentially, a power line acts as a waveguide, which sustains its own electromagnetic modes, which may completely distort whatever signal is sent via the line. The problem had been recognized more than a century ago, and appropriate measures are taken to offset these effects or correct them - you may read more about it in connection to Telegrapher equations.
As for the direct question in the Q.: obviously the phase of generators should be chosen in such a way that the currents are in phase at each point, not the generators themselves (which may be far apart.)

"obviously the phase of generators should be chosen in such a way that the currents are in phase at each point" I believe that's strictly voltage, not current. A generator does not need to supply reactive power to function (e.g. solar inverters don't).

A related problem is instability. I don't think the current means to control synchronization issues using dynamic reactive compensators (as mentioned above) is going to be good enough when there are a large number of green-energy sources (when more and more people on the grid can supply energy to the grid through solar and wind energy). It's been suggested that smart grids are a solution, which would mean that there would have to be additional communication systems in place for the green energy sources. Whether these can prevent all modes of instability (without adding new ones), I really don't know. See,
https://www.hivepower.tech/blog/grid-stability-issues-with-renewable-energy-how-they-can-be-solved
